# Why does adding parentheses after a method call result in "Cannot resolve symbol"?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use [PureConfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) to load a type-safe config.

The following code compiles fine:

```
case class MyConfig(ex1: Boolean, ex2: String)

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig])
  }
}
```

But this does not:

```
case class MyConfig(ex1: Boolean, ex2: String)

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // note the additional parentheses
    println(pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig]())
  }
}
```

It results in "Cannot resolve symbol".

This is the method signature:

```
def loadConfig[Config](implicit reader : pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[Config]]) 
  : scala.Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures, Config]
```

I care, because I would like to do this:

```
import scala.reflect.io.Path
// ...
val path = Path.string2path("/home/test/test.conf")
println(pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig](path))
```

Hopefully resolving to this signature:

```
def loadConfig[Config](path : java.nio.file.Path)(implicit reader : pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[Config]]) 
  : scala.Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures, Config]
```

But that also results in a "Cannot resolve symbol" error.

I come from C#, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

**Update**: as @Luis commented, the first example fails "because you are trying to call the default loader, which does not take any explicit parameter, but it does have some implicits, when you add the empty parenthesis, you are telling the compiler that you will add the implicit argument explicitly, which you didn't".

The second example (passing `path`) fails to compile with this error:

> Error:(8, 34) overloaded method value loadConfig with alternatives:
>   (conf: com.typesafe.config.Config,namespace: String)(implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>      (conf: com.typesafe.config.Config)(implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>      (path: java.nio.file.Path,namespace: String)(implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>      (path: java.nio.file.Path)(implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>      (namespace: String)(implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>      (implicit reader:
>   pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[MyConfig]])Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,MyConfig]
>   cannot be applied to (scala.reflect.io.Path)
>       println(pureconfig.loadConfigMyConfig)

I find that error difficult to read. It seems to be listing methods the compiled *thinks* I might be trying to call. The fourth one in the list is the one I want to call.

Intellij's error is more succinct: "Cannot resolve symbol loadConfig".

Comment: This `pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig](path)` should work. Does it produces any error? - Because this `pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig]()` fails because you are trying to call the default loader, which does not take any explicit parameter, but it does have some implicits, when you add the empty parenthesis, you are telling the compiler that you will add the implicit argument explicitly, which you didn't _(nor you really want)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for helping with the first error! Updated the question with more info about the second error.

Comment: The second error is pretty simple, the method that you want to call expects a `java.nio.file.Path` but you are passing it a `scala.reflect.io.Path` _(which seems is to be a very old and deprecated API)_. I think the best is that you simple do this: `import java.nio.file.Paths` and then `val path = Paths.get("home", "test", "test.conf")`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that's it! If you want to drop it in an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had imported the incorrect type, `scala.reflect.io.Path`. The `loadConfig` method signature wanted `scala.reflect.io.Path`. This code works:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

case class MyConfig(ex1: Boolean, ex2: String)

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val path = Paths.get("/home/test/test.conf")
    println(pureconfig.loadConfig[MyConfig](path))
  }
}
```